# Find the context id inside a block in Moodle

Tags: moodle

How to get the `context` and `context id` in **Moodle 2.9.1**.

Currently I am in a block : **Question Paper**

In form submission action page I need the `context id`. I don't know how to get the `context` is inside a block (or module). My code is look like this:

**question_action.php**

```
require_once(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))).'/config.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/locallib.php');


global $DB, $CFG;
require_once("$CFG->libdir/resourcelib.php");

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
 $cid = $_GET['id'];}  //course id
 if(isset($_GET['poolid'])){
 $paper= $_GET['paper'];} //question paper id
```

How I find the `context` and `context id` here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the block get_content() function, you can get the contextid from $this->context->id.

If you have an extra PHP page within your block, you will need to make sure that any links have some sort of identifier added as a parameter (that could be the courseid, the blockid or the contextid).

Assuming all your links have the courseid at the end of them (probably the most sensible choice), on the page itself you can write:

```
$courseid = required_param('id', PARAM_INT); // Do not use $_GET directly.
$course = $DB->get_record('course', ['id' => $courseid], '*', MUST_EXIST); // Optional, but you often need the course object.
$context = context_course::instance($courseid);
$contextid = $context->id;
```